# bash + command with a variable that has a space in the path

Tags: linux, bash

I am having trouble executing a command that has variables, so I am trying to recreate it here with this simple example.

I want to list the contents of the path `DIR` but because there is a `space` in the path it will not work. 
The problem is the space in the path `/home/User Name/tarfolder`. This works fine if there is no space in the path.

how can I get this to work for paths that have a space in the path?

Also on an aside is it not good practice to have spaces in paths with linux/unix. 
I am working on cygwin on a windows 7 machine, but i am writing my script for a linux server that I use.

SCRIPT:

```
#!/bin/bash

## trying to work on directories here that have spaces in there path 

# get the current directory the script is in
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"  
echo "DIR is equal to:"
echo $DIR

## want to be able to list the contents of the path $DIR that has a space in it
eval 'ls' $DIR
```

OUTPUT::

```
User Name@WNZCL0276 ~/tarfolder
$ ./dir_path_with_space.sh
DIR is equal to:
/home/User Name/tarfolder
ls: cannot access Name/tarfolder: No such file or directory
/home/User
```

I understand i can use escape characters like here, but I don't I can use that in my script above.

```
User Name@WNZCL0276 ~/tarfolder
$ ls /home/User\ Name/tarfolder/
backup.sh  dir_path_with_space.sh  folderToZip  ReadMe.txt
```

Comment: If you _really_ needed to use `eval`, you could run `eval 'ls "$DIR"'`, but... why?

Comment: ...the outer quotes on right-hand side of the assignment don't hurt anything, by the way, but they also aren't necessary: Assignments implicitly prevent string-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: Similarly, `echo "$DIR"` is more correct than `echo $DIR`; if your directory is named `/path/to/ *** my special directory name *** /`, the latter will behave catastrophically (replacing the `*`s with lists of files in the directory where the current command is being run).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `eval`. Do use quotes.

```
dir=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
ls "$dir"
```

By convention, `dir` should be lower-case since it's neither an environment variable nor a shell builtin; following this convention avoids namespace collisions.

---

For a larger discussion of what you're trying to do here (in terms of finding your script's location), see [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028). For a larger discussion of building commands using variables (with contents that can contain spaces and otherwise arbitrary content), see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). For discussion of why `eval` shouldn't be used except when absolutely necessary, see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: tks for all that, I might be lacking in good practice when it comes to bash scripting. Also might have been a simple example for what I want to do. what I want to do is something like `command="tar -cvf $arg1 $arg2"` and the execute the command `eval $command`

Comment: @HattrickNZ, read BashFAQ #50, which describes the correct way to do that (not involving `eval`).

Comment: @HattrickNZ, in case you really want to keep a command in a shell variable and have trouble because parts of the command contain spaces, you should consider holding your command in a bash-array; `eval` can handle (i. e. execute) that as well and you can easily have spaces in parts of the command.

Comment: @Alfe, a command with its exact argv stored in an array can simply be run as `"${array_name[@]}"`; using `eval` throws away many of the benefits from using an array in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear about my intentions to use `eval` only if the things it provides are needed—like an additional evaluation-step of variables.  I just meant that an array would not even rule out the `eval` in case it was necessary.

Comment: @Alfe, ...the problem is that using `eval` puts its arguments through a shell parsing pass, meaning that data (such as filenames) can be treated as code. If you haven't gone to efforts to make your variables eval-safe (perhaps you're working with a directory named for Bobby Tables' brother, `Jim $(rm -rf /)`), that's a Bad Idea.

Comment: That's right, and thank you for pointing it out for us once more.